# How to extract data from MYSQL Json extract with Key name starting with @?

Tags: mysql, sql

The Below query is failing where the key name starts with [ampersand] @type.
Is there a way to fetch the data without updating the Json key name in the table.

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_OBJECT (
    'id',JSON_EXTRACT(INV_MASTER, "$[0].id[0]") ,
    'href',JSON_EXTRACT(INV_MASTER, "$[0].href[0]"),
    '@type',JSON_EXTRACT(INV_MASTER, "$[0].@type[0]"),
    'entityChar',JSON_EXTRACT(INV_MASTER, "$[0].entityChar")
    ))
    as MASTER from PROFILE;
```

This seems to be mysql not allowing some special characters in the Json functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No such problem. You use incorrect JSON paths simply.

Demo:

```
CREATE TABLE test (id INT, val JSON);
INSERT INTO test VALUES 
(1, '[{"id":11, "@value":"value 1"}, {"id":111, "@value":"value 11"}]'),
(2, '[{"id":22, "@value":"value 2"}, {"id":222, "@value":"value 22"}]');
```

```
SELECT id, val->>'$[0]."@value"' value1, val->>'$[1]."@value"' value2
FROM test;
```

| id | value1 | value2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | value 1 | value 11 |
| 2 | value 2 | value 22 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/ITumGpkc)

---

Each quote type char must be used in proper place.

- Single quote **<kbd>'</kbd>** is used for string literal quoting.
- Double quote **<kbd>"</kbd>** is used for JSON path/value quoting.
- Backtick **<kbd>`</kbd>** is used for object name quoting.

In the example above - the path is string literal which is quoted with single quotes (`'$[0]."@value"'`) whereas the value of the level in the JSON path in this string value (`"@value"`) is quoted with double quotes.

Comment: After putting double quotes around the @type it worked  : '$[0]."@type"'

Comment: @Kimi Slightly updated.